Long run average holding cost
I have a single server queue with arrival rate $\lambda$. I have calculated that the steady state waiting time of a customer is $W$. Suppose it is given that the per unit time cost of having a customer wait is $h$. Is it possible to calculate the long run average holding cost from this information?
Intuitively I think that the long run average cost should be equal or proportional to $\lambda W h$. Is this correct? How can I show it?

You're exactly right. The key is a result called Little's law. It says the long-run average number of customers present is $\lambda W$, and thus the average holding cost is $\lambda W h$.
One nice treatment of Little's law is Chapter 27 of Harchol-Balter (2024).
Little's law actually applies to essentially any queueing system, not just single-server queues. The only requirement is the existence of the relevant long-run average quantities.
